# Does a thread lock another thread?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

> 1. Singularity - If a thread managed to lock a mutex, it is assured that ***no other thread will be able to lock the thread*** until the original thread releases the lock.
> 2. Non-Busy Wait - ***If a thread attempts to lock a thread*** that was locked by a second thread, the first thread will be suspended (and will not consume any CPU resources) until the lock is freed by the second thread. At this time, the first thread will wake up and continue execution, having the mutex locked by it.

**From**: Multi-Threaded Programming With POSIX Threads

**Question**: I thought threads lock the mutex variables. Threads don't lock other threads?
What do the bold statements above mean? How can one thread lock other thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrections:

1. If a thread managed to lock a mutex, it is assured that no other thread will be able to lock the `mutex` until the original thread releases the lock.
2. Non-Busy Wait - If a thread attempts to lock a `mutex` that was locked by a second thread, the first thread will be suspended (and will not consume any CPU resources) until the lock is freed by the second thread. At this time, the first thread will wake up and continue execution, having the mutex locked by it.

It's a good thing you don't take for granted whatever you read on the internet, also I give you thumbs up for paying attention to what you read.